# UPDATE command won't insert certain columns into my database in SSMS

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update a table in my database by inserting rows into it from a dataset in the program.

I can see in the watch window that all columns are filled out in the dataset within the program but for some reason the "WeightUnits" and "VibUnits" columns appear as NULL in the database when the update is carried out.

The datatable values just before the update command is attempted are shown here:
[image: 1]

The update command is:

```
OleDbInstrumentation.Update(dsSaveBalance.tblInstrumentation.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.Added Or DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent))
```

The database in SSMS after the update command is carried out is shown here:
[image: 2]

The InsertCommand is shown here: [image: 3]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possibly a mismatch between data types? Though I hope that'd cause an exception rather than update with bad or incomplete data.

Comment: May I ask why exactly you're not just doing this: `OleDbInstrumentation.Update(dsSaveBalance.tblInstrumentation)`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have checked the data types and they do match but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @jmcilhinney I get the same error message either way. And I have also checked the DataViewRowState and the rows in question are in the "added" state so my command should work anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but why are you doing it the more complex way? Is there a reason?

Comment: As for the issue, can you show us the `InsertCommand` of your data adapter?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes it's so that only the rows that have been modified are updated in the table. It's a sort of protection against losing or accidentally modifying other rows in the table.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have added a screenshot in the post itself. I have tried configuring the data adapter and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the SQL query in there

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've managed to find the error thanks to your suggestion to look at the InsertCommand. The tables had slightly different column names. "VibUnit" vs "VibUnits". Adding the "s" solved the issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"It's a sort of protection against losing or accidentally modifying other rows in the table"*.  Then it appears to be misguided. Only rows with a `RowState` of `Modified` can be updated and you're including them anyway. As for losing rows, they'd have to have a `RowState` of `Deleted` in order to be deleted from the database but, if you don't want to delete them from the database, why would you be deleting them in your app?

Comment: For future reference, don't post pictures of code. Post the code as text, formatted as code. We can't copy and paste code from pictures.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The project I am working on is a handover from someone else so to be honest I'm not entirely sure why it was used, I'm assuming as a workaround for something else he couldn't get working. Thank you for all your help.